# RxJs5 emit on absence of movement

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a slider. I want to change color depending on percentage. Apart from this i want to show tooltip if user does not move mouse N seconds.
I can think about possible solution, but this doesn't seems like correct way, is there any better way to accomplish this task?

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(container,"mousemove")
.debounceTime(30)
.switchMap(
   () => Rx.Observable.race(
       Rx.Observable.fromEvent(container,"mousemove").map(
           (v) => "Continue changing color"
       ),
       Rx.Observable.interval(2000).map(
           (v) => "Show tooltip!"
       )
   )
)
.subscribe(
  v => console.log(v)
)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the event source, then switch the sequence to timer that emits after the specified time. When the event source emits, it will create another timer, delaying whatever should happen after it.

```
fromEvent(container,"mousemove")
  .switchMap(() => timer(IDLE_TIME))
  .do(() => { /* show tooltip */ })
  .subscribe()
```